# How to enable 3rd party cookies ONLY for Microsoft Teams

Tags: chat, microsoft-account

The company I work for wants us to begin using [Microsoft Teams](https://products.office.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/group-chat-software) however after logging in the page goes into a redirect loop for about a minute, and then finally ends up on this error screen.

[image: D'oh! To open the web app, you need to change your browser settings to allow third-party cookies.]
I know that I could just open my browser settings (Chrome in my case) and just allow all 3rd party cookies... but I don't want to do that since it would do this for **all websites**.  Unchecking this box **does** solve the issue, but it's not an acceptable resolution to this issue for me.

[image: Chrome Settings - block third-party cookies and site data]

I also know that I can add exceptions to allow thirst party cookies from certain websites.  I've tried adding `teams.microsoft.com` and even just `microsoft.com`, neither one works and I still get this error page.

[image: Chrome Settings - third-party cookie exceptions]

How are you supposed to use Microsoft Teams without allowing every website to add whatever cookies they want to add?  Am I missing something obvious here?  It's worth noting that I've also disabled my adblocker software for this domain.

Comment: This would seem to be a web browser issue, no? As such it belongs on [su].

Comment: This is how Microsoft Teams seems to work out of the box.  You have to make local setting changes just to be able to use their website.  I'm happy to move the question there if needed, but to me it seems like other might wan to know how they are supposed to visit this website without requiring a browser security hole.

Comment: To provide Microsoft Teams feedback upvote this: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/18681580-acknowledge-exceptions-for-third-party-cookies-ins

Comment: This is absolutely horrible, and Microsoft should fix their damn website instead of forcing users to use less secure browser settings. Ugh....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A workaround seems to be to just skip the web app and download their desktop application instead: https://teams.microsoft.com/downloads

Comment: Which works if you're on macOS or Windows, not Linux.

Comment: This would open more security holes than adding a browser exception.

Comment: @James you're mixing up two completely different things. Downloading one app is a security risk because it requires trusting one company (not any company). This superuser question is not really about security, it's about privacy and not being tracked by ALL websites on the internet.

Comment: @MarcH It depends on what the app does, and what access it has. Better to use a fresh (trusted) broswer profile only for this than use an app.

Comment: @retorquere Miracles do happen. Now there is a native Linux version. I've just installed it.

Comment: Funnily i come here because linux app show's same error

Answer (score 38):

Add a cookie exception for **https://login.microsoftonline.com**. This worked for me at least.

Comment: This worked until 2FA was enabled.

Answer (score 10):

I added all 4 entries and teams.microsoft.com is now working in Chrome with 3rd party cookies disabled.  Thanks for the posts.

**Where to add**

chrome://settings/content/cookies  under Allow

**What I added**

[*.]microsoft.com

[*.]microsoftonline.com

[*.]skype.com

[*.]online.lync.com

Comment: It seems like this answer should be marked as the solution: Succinct and does the trick. It does not, however discuss the check box "allow third party...". I checked that, but it may not be necessary.

Answer (score 9):

After login you can check in Chrome what cookies it uses. [image]

Third party would be:   **.skype.com** and maybe **.online.lync.com**

If you use IE you might have *.microsoft.com in your Trusted Zone but .skype.com is not and IE/Edge will throw error. (as sites are in different zones)

At the bottom left (click on the guid error code d928....) of your screenshot you can download a log file (to check details what URL are called and what the issue is)

Answer (score 2):

As [Ed B](https://superuser.com/users/776592/ed-b) has already written it is sufficient to enter the URL **https://login.microsoftonline.com**.

To distribute the setting in a company you can set the following regestry value:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\CookiesAllowedForUrls]
"1"="https://login.microsoftonline.com"
```

To use wildcards in the Chrome Application (answer from [Tilo](https://superuser.com/users/216033/tilo)), use this syntax:

```
[*.]skype.com
[*.]online.lync.com
```

Else the URL can not be entered. However, I did not have to add the two pages

Source: [CLICK](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#CookiesAllowedForUrls)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an exception to chrome for both:

- `[*.]microsoft.com`
- `[*.]microsoftonline.com`

Answer (score 0):

On my Chrome 67 on Ubuntu 16.04 I had the exact same message saying that I needed to enable third party cookies. Since on my system these were already allowed this was apparently an incorrect error message.

On my system the Teams website started to work after I removed all locally stored data from Chrome that was related to the teams.microsoft.com website and then pressed the `Try Again` button.

Effectively I simply did `REMOVE ALL` under [chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=teams.microsoft.com](http://chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=teams.microsoft.com). If this link does not work for you then use  [chrome://settings/siteData](http://chrome://settings/siteData) and search `teams.microsoft.com`

Answer (score 0):

Many of these answers are good and solve the issue of the loop, however, they do not actually answer the question of adding third party links for JUST the parent URL.  (I had solved my on login loop by allowing the 3rd party cookies under https:teams.microsoft.com, and searching for how to do this programmatically led me to this question.)

It's documented [here in this question under @JuniorAdmin's](https://superuser.com/a/1444309/1574124) answer that we're able to change the registry values to force a site's cookies as an exception (tested and validated in my own setup - see screenshots below).
[image: Registry where the edit took place]
[image: Chrome Settings showing the Cookie Allowance]

> To add the 3rd Party Cookies to a given URL you need to use two `URL Patterns`; the Syntax is as follows:
>
> `ThirdPartyCookieURLPattern,ParentURLPattern`
>
> Example:
>
> `https://stackoverflow.com,https://superuser.com`
>
> `*,https://teams.microsoft.com`
>
> This would allow 3rd party cookies from only Stack Overflow to be
> executed in Super User, or ALL 3rd party cookies for Microsoft Teams.

Applying this, we are able to enforce this change.  (In these screenshots, I've specified I want ALL third party cookies from the other 2 parent URL's I used in the initial test from screenshots above.)
[image: Registry set to include '*,' in the comma separated URL.]
[image: Chrome Settings showing the 3rd Party Cookie Allowance]

---

## Sources

Despite @JuniorAdmin's answer to this question, I did not learn about the Registry path from there.  I found it [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9131254?hl=en#zippy=%2Cconfigure-settings-on-windows-computers:%7E:text=The%20Chrome%20browser,any%20text%20editor.), where it referenced downloading a Bundle [from this link](https://enterprise.google.com/chrome/chrome-browser/#download)'.
(Perform a Bundle Download for your Architecture (`32-bit, 64-bit`) and then extract the bundle. Under the `Configuration\examples\` directory, edit the `Chrome.reg` file as referenced to see what all can be set.  Not sure if it contains every flag known, but it is fairly exhaustive.)

I stumbled upon the augmentation of the URL using 2 different `URL Patterns` from a [Reddit article](https://www.reddit.com/r/Intune/comments/wsdscj/how_to_allow_thirdparty_cookies_only_on_specific/ir9qs2k/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) `(justlittleme123's answer specifies it clearly)`, which led to an [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#example-value-8:%7E:text=To%20allow%20third,value%20does%20not) that specifies it in case anyone needs to do this programmatically `(pulled from justlittleme123's answer including highlighting, in case their answer is removed from Reddit)`. . .